# Exploit vulnerable projects using RBF policy

Tags: security, replace-by-fee

If a project is vulnerable to some type of RBF policies, how could an attacker exploit this project?

Answer (score 1):

An attacker with some nodes using RBF policy that will be used for the attack and some miners using same policy is all that's required to exploit vulnerable projects.

> All you need is for there to be *a* path that follows the new relay rules
> and gets from your node/wallet to perhaps 10% of hashpower

https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-February/019846.html